# NoClassDefFoundError: NameCoder at Spring Cloud Brixton.SR7 and Spring Cloud Camden.SR3

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

For all the Camden releases and now on the Brixton.SR7 as well, the following issue related to the Eureka Client occurs when starting the Spring Boot app:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/naming/NameCoder`

For an instance I have a Spring Boot app having the `@EnableDiscoveryClient` annotation...

Lately I’ve been changing the Spring Cloud dependencies back to Brixton.SR6 in order to get rid of this error. Certainly, I want to use the latest versions of the Spring Cloud but how could I fix this error the right way?

Thanks

The console output is the following:

```
2016-11-30 13:09:50.166  INFO 9248 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2016-11-30 13:09:50.177 ERROR 9248 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:176) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:51) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:346) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:112) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:545) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
    at com.citifintech.ReferenceZipkinServiceApplication.main(ReferenceZipkinServiceApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.eurekaClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/netflix/eureka/EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$2.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:359) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:176) ~[spring-cloud-context-1.1.6.RELEASE.jar:1.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192) ~[spring-aop-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy82.getApplications(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java:120) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.start(EurekaDiscoveryClientConfiguration.java:97) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:173) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.netflix.discovery.EurekaClient]: Factory method 'eurekaClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to initialize DiscoveryClient!
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:441) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:304) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:51) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:192) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1700a5f.CGLIB$eurekaClient$1(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1700a5f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$3759430b.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c1700a5f.eurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:1.2.3.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/xstream/io/naming/NameCoder
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers$XStreamXml.<init>(CodecWrappers.java:358) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.create(CodecWrappers.java:133) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.getEncoder(CodecWrappers.java:75) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.converters.wrappers.CodecWrappers.getEncoder(CodecWrappers.java:66) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider.<init>(DiscoveryJerseyProvider.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder$MyDefaultApacheHttpClient4Config.<init>(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.EurekaJerseyClientImpl$EurekaJerseyClientBuilder.build(EurekaJerseyClientImpl.java:170) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.buildLegacy(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:205) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory$JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactoryBuilder.build(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:186) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.create(JerseyEurekaHttpClientFactory.java:143) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.TransportClientFactories.newTransportClientFactory(TransportClientFactories.java:49) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.scheduleServerEndpointTask(DiscoveryClient.java:477) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:428) ~[eureka-client-1.4.12.jar:1.4.12]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.naming.NameCoder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

Here is the pom.xml :
`    
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.financial</groupId>
<artifactId>demo</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>client-service</name>
<description>Reference application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Camden.SR3</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Here is the main class of the application:

```
package com.financial;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;

@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class ClientServiceApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ClientServiceApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Finally the `bootstrap.properties`

```
spring.application.name=client-service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
```

Comment: We've never seen that before. Care to share a project that recreates the problem?

Comment: Hi, Spence      Just added the `pom.xml`, `bootstrap.properties` and the main class of the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had some time to take a closer look into this issue… so the exception is caused by the absence of the `NameCoder` class in the `xstream` library. This library is used by `Eureka` implementation.

Now then, `xstream` latest version to this date is 1.4.9 which is the one that is included on the managed dependencies for `Camden.SR3` and `Brixton.SR7`.

The latest version that includes the `NameCoder` class is the `xstream-1.4.8` so I had to modify the `pom.xml` right where the eureka dependency is stated, for all of my projects have eureka server or client to use the dependency `xstream` version 1.4.8 instead of the provided by the `Camden.SR3` managed dependencies. For sure in maven there are several alternatives to accomplish this depending of the structure of the project, but the most straight forward way is as follows:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>                        
        </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
</dependency>       

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
    <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.8</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
</dependency>
```

Now then, the point to notice is that how the Eureka current implementations  use the `NameCoder` class being that the version of the `xstream` library provided by the Spring Cloud `Camden.SR3` and `Brixton.SR7` releases is `xstream-1.4.9` which doesn’t have precisely this class?  Possibly this issue went under the radar during the testing bundle because of some multiple dependencies that maven ended up solving automatically, however when implementing Eureka service with the latest release of Spring Cloud it will be necessary to do this change, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. This is related to an old inclusion of xstream (`xstream:xstream:jar:1.1.3:compile`).
The xstream library change groupId and Spring cloud use a new version (`com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.9:compile`).

Use `mvn dependency:tree` command to check if you have the two library in your classpath. Then you can use maven exclusions to remove the old one from your classpath.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>GROUPID</groupId>
    <artifactId>ARTIFACTID</artifactId>
    <version>X.Y.Z</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>xstream</groupId>
            <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```